# If/else for INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am running into a situation where I cannot figure out the best way to run an if/else query. First, I am not sure if I can run an if/else with an sql statement. Below is what I currently have. Through this process, I only added the if/else around the query.

Basically what I want to do is run the first query if it equals `$user_id` otherwise, run the else, which I want to make the value of `user_id` (database column - not the variable listed above) equal to `$profile_viewer`.

So, in a nutshell, if I can do this, I am just not sure how to modify my execute:

To include `$profile_viewer` to be the parameter for the else query.

`$select_img_stmt->execute(array($user_id));`

```
    $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
    $profile_viewer = $_GET['user'];
    if ($profile_viewer == $user_id) {
        $img_select_sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM profile_img
            WHERE user_id = ?
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ";
    }
    else {
        //echo "This is not your image";
        $img_select_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM profile_img
            WHERE user_id = ?
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ";
    }
    if ($select_img_stmt = $con->prepare($img_select_sql)) {
        $select_img_stmt->execute(array($user_id));
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
    $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
    $profile_viewer = $_GET['user'];
    if ($profile_viewer == $user_id) {
        /*$img_select_sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM profile_img
            WHERE user_id = ?
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ";*/
        $img_select_sql = "
            SELECT i.*
            FROM profile_img i
            WHERE user_id IN (?, ?)
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 1;
        ";
    }
    else {
        //echo "This is not your image";
        echo $profile_viewer;
    }
    if ($select_img_stmt = $con->prepare($img_select_sql)) {
        $select_img_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $profile_viewer));
```

Comment: That seems to be ok. Do the session and GET arrays contain values? any errors at all via php and the query? what happens when you do run this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, it works in the if, but not the else. I need there to be two different parameters in the execute, `$user_id` and `$profile_viewer`

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with my question.

Comment: you mention you have errors in Gordon's answer *"but I get errors when I am initiating the else part of my code"* - but didn't state what they are

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I did state what the error was. The code is expecting `$img_select_sql`. Since I only have it in the if section, when the results triggers the else, it breaks. Errors from page.... `Notice: Undefined variable: img_select_sql in` and `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing all this in one query?

```
SELECT i.*
FROM profile_img i
WHERE user_id IN ($user_id, $profile_viewer)
ORDER BY (user_id = $user_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This has put the variable values directly in the code for clarity.  Of course, I recommend using parameters rather than munging the query string with the values.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get errors when I am initiating the else part of my code. Since I only have one query, it is expecting the `$img_select_sql`. See updated code in my question.

Comment: The following errors are from only having the query in the if section of the code. `Notice: Undefined variable: img_select_sql in` and `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty` For when the if condition fails.